# Draw top half of video to canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

I'm using `context.drawImage` to draw from a `video` element to a `canvas`, but my camera has an aspect ration of 4x3.

So let's say I have my `video` with width 400 and height 300, then I want to draw the top half (400x150) to the canvas (or middle, doesn't matter, as long as it's half of the height).

Everything I've tried either changes the aspect ration of the image distorting it or draws at the same 4x3 aspect ration, meaning it cuts down to 200x150 and then scales to fit my 400x150 canvas, i.e., it draws half of the height, but also cuts the width in half too.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: `ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight/2, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight/2)`

Comment: Have you tried that? I just tried and it didn't work, same behavior, cutting the width too.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, example bellow:

```js
let video = document.createElement('video');
video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
  let w = video.videoWidth;
  let h = video.videoHeight;
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  // cut top half and scale it to 50% canvas
  canvas.width  = w/2;
  canvas.height = h/4;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h/2, 0, 0, w/2, h/4)
});
video.src = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4#t=10";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```